# Call C++ functions from C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, unmanaged

I have a solution which has a C++ project and a C# project.

The C++ project defines a class, which I want to instantiate in C# and call its member functions. So far I managed to instantiate the class:

```
CFoo Bar = new CFoo();
```

But when I try to call a function on it, the compiler says, it is not available.

Also, when I inspect the object in the debugger, no members are shown.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the C++ project a managed C++ project or an unmanaged one?

Comment: it is compiled with /clr (Common Language Runtime Support) if that is what you mean.

Comment: You have solution of this ??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929737/using-native-c-class-in-c-sharp
Read my post and help me on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to declare the class in C++/CLI as a `ref class`.

(Note that we're talking about C++/CLI, not C++. I assume you must have enabled the CLR in your C++ project or you wouldn't be able to get the new `CFoo` to work.)

**Edit:**

You don't need to convert all your old classes in to `ref` classes.

Suppose you have some old C++:

```
class FooUnmanaged
{
    int x;

    FooUnmanaged() : x(5) {}
};
```

Then you try to wrap it in a CLR class:

```
ref class FooManaged
{
    FooUnmanaged m;
};
```

As you've noticed, you get an error saying this isn't allowed. But try this:

```
ref class FooManaged
{
    FooUnmanaged *m;
};
```

That's perfectly OK. The compiler doesn't want to allocate an instance of an unmanaged object embedded inside an object on the managed heap, but it's quite happy to have a pointer, which it turns into `System.IntPtr` in the resulting IL.

This means that you have to make a decision about how to call `delete`. The most likely solution is:

```
ref class FooManaged
{
    FooUnmanaged *u;

public:
    FooManaged(FooUnmanaged *u_)
        : u(u_) { }

    ~FooManaged() { delete u; }
};
```

Just as it would be in any other C++ class. It's possible that C++/CLI will be able to do this translation for us automatically in some future version.

Note that the resulting IL is that the `FooManaged` class now implements `IDisposable`, and the destructor has been turned into a `Dispose` method. This allows .NET clients to properly deallocate it, e.g. in C#

```
using (var m = new FooManaged())
{

    // end of block: m will be disposed (and so FooUnmanaged will be deleted)
}
```

Comment: thanks, if i do this i get a lot of errors like: 
Error 1 error C2814: a native type cannot be nested within a managed type . 

i guess that means that i need to change the members to managed types. is there a way to avoid this?