# C++ class with CString to C#

Tags: c#, c++, class, pinvoke, marshalling

How do I return data held in a C++ class containing a CString to C#?

My C++ class:

```
class Item
{
public:
    AFX_EXT_CLASS Item();
    AFX_EXT_CLASS ~Item();
    int m_nType;
    int m_nField;
    double m_dVal;
    int m_nVal;
    CString m_sVal;
};
```

The Item class is used like this in C++:

```
    Item MyObject::GetVal(int nField)
    {
        Item Val;
        ...
        return Val;
    }
...
Item Val = GetVal(i);
```

Ideally this Item object would be usable in C# as a class or struct with ints, doubles and string members.

I have managed to retrieve a C++ struct containing int and char* but I'm not sure how to code the solution for the CString and a class.  **I can't change the Item class.**

My solution for a struct was:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) WINUSERUI* jCallValidateUser(LPTSTR sUser, LPTSTR sEditPass)
{
    winLogin->ValidateUser(sUser, sEditPass);
    return &winLogin->twu;  // where WINUSERUI twu
}

typedef struct WINUSERUI
{
    int m_nUser;
    char *m_sUser;
    char *m_sUserStatus;
    char *m_sDomain;
    int m_nLevel;
    int m_nTimeout;
    int bLogonOK;
    char *m_sPassword;
} WinUserUI;
```

Then in C#:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct WinUserUI
    {
        public int m_nUser;
        public string m_sUser;
        public string m_sUserStatus;
        public string m_sDomain;
        public int m_nLevel;
        public int m_nTimeout;
        public int bLogonOK;
        public string m_sPassword;
    }

    [DllImportAttribute("MyDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "jCallValidateUser")]
    static private extern IntPtr jCallValidateUser(string username, string password);

    public static WinUserUI ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        var ptr = jCallValidateUser(username, password);
        return (WinUserUI)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(WinUserUI));
    }
```

Used like this:

```
WinUserUI twu = ValidateUser(username, password);
```

I've read about PInvoke but the solutions seem overly complex for my need.... or maybe I do need a more complex solution than I'm expecting. This is my sticking point.

A couple of many articles read:
[Call C++ functions from C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170892/call-c-functions-from-c-net) and 
[How to Marshal a C++ Class](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/18032/how-to-marshal-a-c-class)

Your thoughts/solutions/words of wisdom are very welcome.
Steve

Comment: Add your own struct with the proper type and P/Invoke through that one. To export a class with `CString` object is a bad idea even without P/Invoke in the middle...

Comment: Can you use C++/CLI in your C# project? That would facilitate the marshalling a lot.

Comment: I have used a CLR DLL to call C# from C++ before, but that only involved ints.

Comment: @Steve: using C++/CLI involves 3 projects. The C++ DLL, a C++/CLI DLL and the C# Dll. Is that possible for you?

Comment: yes, we already have C++ DLL, C# DLL, a CLR C++ DLL. The more the merrier!  I still have not seen a clear example on how to achieve what I need.

Comment: Write code that do the conversion in C++/CLI. You won't be able to use your C++ native class with P/Invoke.